# Can we show exactness of some terms in Snake's Lemma using category theory only?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I am trying to see how far I can get with Snake Lemma in Abelian Category with only Category Theory, in other words, not appealing to $R$-module just yet. So please consider the following commutative diagram:

\begin{array}{c}
& & A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{g} & C & \to & 0 \\
& & \downarrow a & & \downarrow b & & \downarrow c \\
0 & \to & A' & \xrightarrow{f'} & B' & \xrightarrow{g'} & C' 
\end{array}

By definition we have $\ker a\to A$ etc and similarly for $A'\to\text{coker}a$. Thus the updated diagram would look like:

\begin{array}{c}
& & \ker a & \xrightarrow{} & \ker b & \xrightarrow{} & \ker c  \\
& & \downarrow a & & \downarrow b & & \downarrow c \\
& & A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{g} & C & \to & 0 \\
& & \downarrow a & & \downarrow b & & \downarrow c \\
0 & \to & A' & \xrightarrow{f'} & B' & \xrightarrow{g'} & C'
\end{array}

(Sorry I omitted the coker terms)

and that the map from $\ker a\to \ker b$ is the canonical one using universal property of kernels.

My question: From this universal construction so far, is $\ker a\to \ker b\to \ker c$ exact at $\ker b$ using Category Theory alone?

I am aware what to prove but I have not got much of a clue how to prove it and so any help would be very very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Here's a couple hints:

1. Let's denote the morphisms $\ker a\rightarrow\ker b$ by $\tilde{f}$ and $\ker b\rightarrow\ker c$ by $\tilde{g}$. Construct a commutative diagram
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   \ker a @>>> \mathrm{im}\tilde{f} @>>> \ker b\\
   @VVV @VVV @VVV  \\
   A @>>> \mathrm{im}f @>>> B\\
   @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
   A^{\prime} @>>> \mathrm{im}f^{\prime} @>>> B^{\prime}
   \end{CD}.$$
   Here, the rows are supposed to be the obvious factorizations of $\tilde{f}$, $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ respectively.
2. Note that exactness of $A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}B\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}C$ at $B$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{im}f\rightarrow B$ being a kernel of $g$ and that exactness of $\ker a\stackrel{\tilde{f}}{\rightarrow}\ker b\stackrel{\tilde{g}}{\rightarrow}\ker c$ at $\ker b$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{im}\tilde{f}\rightarrow\ker b$ being a kernel of $\tilde{g}$. The latter can be deduced from the former by directly verifying the universal property through a chase in the diagram
   $$\begin{CD}
   0@>>> \mathrm{im}\tilde{f} @>>> \ker b @>{\tilde{g}}>> \ker c @.\\
   @. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
   0@>>> \mathrm{im}f @>>> B @>{g}>> C\\
   @. @VVV @VV{b}V @VV{c}V  \\
   0@>>> \mathrm{im}f^{\prime} @>>> B' @>{g'}>> C'
   \end{CD}.$$

Remark: You can additionally observe that $\mathrm{im}\tilde{f}\rightarrow\mathrm{im}f$ is a kernel of $\mathrm{im}f\rightarrow\mathrm{im}f^{\prime}$, so that the argument can be summarized as first convincing ourselves that we may assume $f$ (and hence $\tilde{f}$) to be monic, and then verifying the claim in the monic case directly.

If you're comfortable with more high-powered language, one can note that the category $\mathrm{Arr}(\mathcal{A})$ of arrows in the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ itself is an abelian category, taking kernels yields a functor $\mathrm{Arr}(\mathcal{A})\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$, this functor possess a left-adjoint $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathrm{Arr}(\mathcal{A})$, acting on objects as $X\mapsto(X\rightarrow0)$, hence the functor is left-exact, whence preserves three-term exact sequences, which is what's being inquired about. These last claims require a lot of detail checks, however, which contain the insights of the more elementary approach, so this is less a shortcut and more a summary, if one is familiar with these concepts.

Lastly, let me add that $g$ being epimorphic and $f^{\prime}$ being monomorphic is completely irrelevant to any of what I said (but very relevant to the later parts of the snake lemma).